# Meaning of window.XMLHttpRequest? (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ajaxform

I have a question about this code:

```
var Request = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

What is the use of `if(window.XMLHttpRequest)` and `if(window.ActiveXObject)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` part checks if an `XMLHttpRequest` object can be created without throwing an error.
If everything goes well, it assigns a name to the object that will be used for "talking with the server".
If this throws an error, it means that the user has an older browser (IE 5 or IE6), so instead it tries to create an `ActiveXObject` which is essentially the same but works only for these older browsers.

You can find more information about this in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_compatibility).